Defining Objects using a Table or Loop
Suppose I want to define weight[] on a list. For instance I want weight[a]:=3, weight[b]:=5, etc. I tried to do this using the code below.
objects = {a, b, c};
Table[weight[objects[[i]]] := 2 i + 1, {i, 1, Length[objects]}];
weight[a]

To my surprise weight[a]  returns 1+2i. Why does this not return 3? I've run into similar issues before when I try and define a sequence of functions in this way.
What is a more appropriate way to define a series of quantities like this, without manually entering them all?

Use = (Set) instead of := (SetDelayed)
objects = {a, b, c};
Table[weight[objects[[i]]] = 2  i + 1, {i, 1, Length[objects]}];
weight[a]

(*3*)

